# How to edit 2 rows in 2 different (but identical structure) database tables - Delphi

Tags: mysql, sql, database, delphi

I use 2 `TDBGrid` controls in my application.

- The 1st DBGrid shows data from a table named `Orders`.
- The 2nd DBGrid shows data from a table named `Archive`.

Both tables are in the same database, and have identical structure (same number and names of columns, as well as same settings).

Here is the structure for both tables:

[image]

I use 2 actions in my application:

- The 1st action is `Add Order`.
- The 2nd action is `Edit Order`.

When I use the `Add Order` form, it successfully adds details I enter into a new row in both tables.

So this works.

Now, I want to select one of those rows I just added and edit its information.

I use the `Edit Order` action for that.  It displays a similar form with the information to edit and save.  It should edit the info in both tables.  It does, but the IDs change and I end up editing something on the 1st DBGrid, and in the 2nd DBGrid it changes the information to something else (from another ID).

Here is my code for the `Edit` action:

```
procedure TForm2.actEditComandaExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (dbmodule.SQLConnection1.Connected) and (dbmodule.comenziDataSet.IsEmpty = false) then
  begin
    editcustomerform.Edit1.Text := dbmodule.comenziDataSetstare.Value;
    editcustomerform.Edit2.Text := dbmodule.comenziDataSetclient.Value;
    editcustomerform.Edit3.Text := dbmodule.comenziDataSettelefon.Value;
    editcustomerform.Edit4.Text := dbmodule.comenziDataSetemail.Value;
    editcustomerform.Edit5.Text := dbmodule.comenziDataSetdetalii.Value;
    editcustomerform.Edit6.Text := dbmodule.comenziDataSetpret.Value;
    editcustomerform.Edit7.Text := dbmodule.comenziDataSetlivrare.Value;
    editcustomerform.Edit8.Text := dbmodule.comenziDataSetuser.Value;
    editcustomerform.Edit9.Text := dbmodule.comenziDataSetstatus.Value;
    if editcustomerform.ShowModal = mrOk then
    begin
      dbmodule.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
      dbmodule.SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('UPDATE `tipotask`.`comenzi` SET `stare`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit1.Text + ''', `client`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit2.Text + ''', `telefon`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit3.Text + ''', `email`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit4.Text + ''', `detalii`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit5.Text + ''', `pret`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit6.Text + ''', `livrare`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit7.Text + ''', `user`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit8.Text + ''', `status`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit9.Text + ''' WHERE `id`=''' + IntToStr(dbmodule.comenziDataSetid.Value) + ''';');
      dbmodule.SQLQuery1.ExecSQL(true);
      dbmodule.SQLQuery3.SQL.Clear;
      dbmodule.SQLQuery3.SQL.Add('UPDATE `tipotask`.`arhiva` SET `stare`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit1.Text + ''', `client`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit2.Text + ''', `telefon`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit3.Text + ''', `email`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit4.Text + ''', `detalii`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit5.Text + ''', `pret`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit6.Text + ''', `livrare`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit7.Text + ''', `user`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit8.Text + ''', `status`=''' + editcustomerform.Edit9.Text + ''' WHERE `id`=''' + IntToStr(dbmodule.arhivaDataSetid.Value) + ''';');
      dbmodule.SQLQuery3.ExecSQL(true);

      //we need to refresh the data
      actRefreshData.Execute;
    end;
  end;
```

Here is a video of what's happening. Please notice how the ID columns change and mess things up.

[video removed - no need - solved](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sputWPZeMzI)

The end goal is to add a new order using the `Add Order` form, which works well, this adds the order in the 2 tables. This works well.

Whenever I need to `Edit` an order, I just select it in the `Orders` DBGrid and edit it. Once I do that, it should also change the corresponding information in the `Archive` table - just the record I'm editing.

How can I fix this?

I've been at it for a couple of hours now, and I can't figure it out. I don't understand ID fields properly (auto increment, primary, unique, index, etc). I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I'm fairly new, so please do try to provide a complete explanation.

Comment: You use `AdoTable` ?

Comment: Why on Earth are you using a data-ware control (TDBGrid) to display data, but non-db-aware TEDits to edit it?  Why not use TDBEdits?

Comment: @Sami, he uses dbExpress (TSQLConnection instead of TADOConnection).

Comment: @Sami Yes, as Marc mentioned I use dbexpress.

Comment: @MartynA - Hello, thanks for the comment. Because I'm new to delphi and have been trying to make this software reading tutorials and using code off those tutorials. Obviously sooner or later that's going to be a problem but I'm under a time constraint and I can't afford to learn everything and do it later / over time. I'm trying to learn as I go. Plus I need the application for my business so that's why I'm trying to make it. I will lookup TDBEdit, thanks!

Comment: Well, by avoiding the relatively short and gentle learning curve of db-ware controls, you're just creating a whole lot of avoidable problems for yourself.  You end up massively re-inventing a bad design for a totally unnecessary wheel.  Take less than a day getting up to speed with TDBEdit and its brethren and you'll realise what an appalling waste of time the way you're going about it now actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the video you showed, the only way this can be happening is if `dbmodule.arhivaDataSetid.Value` is 1 when `dbmodule.comenziDataSetid.Value` is 3 instead.  And it is clearly visible in the video that before you edit the **3rd** record in the `Orders` DBGrid, you left the **1st** record in the `Archive` DBGrid selected instead of the **3rd** record.

Assuming the `id` values in both tables should always match each other for any given record, you should be using `dbmodule.comenziDataSetid.Value` instead of `dbmodule.arhivaDataSetid.Value` in both SQL statements when editing the `Orders` DBGrid.  Likewise, when editing the `Archive` table, you should be using `dbmodule.arhivaDataSetid.Value` in both SQL statements.  That way, you use the correct ID in both statements.

Alternatively, simply don't use multiple SQL statements at all.  Use DB triggers instead to automatically insert/update a record in one table when a record is inserted/updated in the other table.  No need to duplicate the work in code when the DB engine can do it for you on the server side.

That being said, the `id` field of each table is an *auto-increment* field, which means the value for that table gets incremented automatically whenever a new record is inserted into that table.  So, if there is ever a time that a record is successfully inserted in one table but fails to insert into the other table, you will easily get your IDs out of sync.  So, at the very least, your 2 `INSERT` statements should be wrapped inside a DB transaction so that if either `INSERT` fails, you can cancel the whole transaction without changing either table (same with your `UPDATE` statements).  Also, you should consider having a foreign key reference on the two `id` fields to link them together so that if anyone ever deletes a record in one table, the corresponding record in the other table will be deleted as well.

Personally, I wouldn't rely on using auto-increment fields to link data in two tables together.  Auto-increment fields are fine for identifying records within individual tables, but when data needs to be linked across tables, it is better to use a more reliable and unique identifier, such as an order number, or even a UUID.

Also, be aware that your code is subject to SQL injection attacks. You really should be using parameterized queries instead of manually building SQL statements.  Or, at least use `QuotedStr()` instead of manually putting quotes around user-entered text.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your informative post, it does clear up a bunch of things. I knew it was subject to sql injection but it doesn't really matter since the software will be used in my office by just 5 people on 5 pc's - no internet / nothing and they don't really have any clue about sql and stuff. But yes, I suppose it's good practice to learn the proper way and avoid it all together, I will be looking to chance it and use params instead. How would a DB Trigger look, the one you mentioned? It does sound to do things smoother but I don't know how to use / implement that, thanks again!

Comment: See [Using Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html) in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your problem is in the updating of those tables :

```
  dbmodule.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  dbmodule.SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('UPDATE `tipotask`.`comenzi` SET .... WHERE `id`=''' + IntToStr(dbmodule.comenziDataSetid.Value) + ''';');
  dbmodule.SQLQuery1.ExecSQL(true);
  dbmodule.SQLQuery3.SQL.Clear;
  dbmodule.SQLQuery3.SQL.Add('UPDATE `tipotask`.`arhiva` SET .... WHERE `id`=''' + IntToStr(dbmodule.arhivaDataSetid.Value) + ''';');
  dbmodule.SQLQuery3.ExecSQL(true);
```

As you say, the problem is with the ID, but no because of being autoincrement, indexed, ..., but because you are updating with the same values the focused record on both grids, which normally will be different records (two different IDs).

You should have two different update actions, and depending if you are editing over a grid or over the other, you should use the ID on that grid for both updates.

First one (when you are editing on Comenzi's Grid) :

```
  dbmodule.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  dbmodule.SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('UPDATE `tipotask`.`comenzi` SET .... WHERE `id`=''' + IntToStr(dbmodule.comenziDataSetid.Value) + ''';');
  dbmodule.SQLQuery1.ExecSQL(true);
  dbmodule.SQLQuery3.SQL.Clear;
  dbmodule.SQLQuery3.SQL.Add('UPDATE `tipotask`.`arhiva` SET .... WHERE `id`=''' + IntToStr(dbmodule.comenziDataSetid.Value) + ''';');
  dbmodule.SQLQuery3.ExecSQL(true);
```

And second one (when you are editing on Archiva's Grid) :

```
  dbmodule.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  dbmodule.SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('UPDATE `tipotask`.`comenzi` SET .... WHERE `id`=''' + IntToStr(dbmodule.arhivaDataSetid.Value) + ''';');
  dbmodule.SQLQuery1.ExecSQL(true);
  dbmodule.SQLQuery3.SQL.Clear;
  dbmodule.SQLQuery3.SQL.Add('UPDATE `tipotask`.`arhiva` SET .... WHERE `id`=''' + IntToStr(dbmodule.arhivaDataSetid.Value) + ''';');
  dbmodule.SQLQuery3.ExecSQL(true);
```

A more elegant solution would be to have a single update procedure, and pass dbmodule.arhivaDataSetid.Value or dbmodule.arhivaDataSetid.Value depending on what grid you were editing.

Comment: Hey there, indeed your answer helped. I won't be editing on the Archive dbgrid just on the Orders one so your 2nd code helps with that. It does edit the corresponding entry in the archives also which I was aiming for, since they're the same ID and always will be. Thanks a lot :)